# How can I replace specific word combinations in a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning javascript, and trying to automate a program that automatically detects unshortened acronyms and replaces it in a body of text. For example, let's say I want all "Lord of the Rings" phrases to be replaced with LotR.

I am trying

`string = string.replace("the Lord of the Rings", "LotR");`

but it doesn't seem to do anything. Maybe I should look into `string.search()` function instead, even if it seems to take more steps? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is `string` here? It should be `let string = "the Lord of the Rings"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  `replace()` method to replace all occurrences of a word or substring inside another string.

Let's check out the code :

```
<script>
    var myStr = "the Lord of the Rings";
    var newStr = myStr.replace(/the Lord of the Rings/g, "LotR");
    
    // Printing the modified string
    document.write(newStr);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need first to declare your variable to apply replace() method, try this:

```js
let str = "the Lord of the Rings";
str = str.replace("the Lord of the Rings", "LotR");
console.log(str)
```

If you want to match every "the Lord of the Rings" in your string, you can use a global flag (g) into the first argument in replace():

```js
let str = "the Lord of the Rings the Lord of the Rings";
str = str.replace(/the Lord of the Rings/g, "LotR");
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use string as a variable.

Also you do not show what string is initialized to.
example

```
var mystring = "I like the movie the Lord of the Rings";
mystring = mystring.replace("the Lord of the Rings","LotR");
```

Mystring now contains  "I like the movie LotR"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all instances of the word with the acronym, you should do:

```
let str = 'Lord of the Rings is the best movie series ever, and Lord of the Rings is also a series of books. ';

let result = str.replaceAll("Lord of the Rings", "LotR");
```

String.replaceAll() is supported by most modern browsers, but you can check if it is supported on your target platform using [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceAll).

You can also do `str.split("Lord of the Rings").join("LotR")` if you want to make it more backwards compatible.

Or you can use regular expressions:

`str.replace(/the Lord of the Rings/g, "LotR");`

And if you want to make it so the replacement is insensitive to case:

`str.replace(/the Lord of the Rings/ig, "LotR");`